# What is the proper way of resetting a password?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Until today, I used `UserManager`'s `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` method to generate tokens. AFAIK, it is implemented by ASP.NET Identity.

But, I just found out about `UserManager`'s `SetNewPasswordResetCode` method implemented by ABP.

I understand the differences between both. Why didn't ABP reimplement or use Identity's methods?

Also, which should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They are same. The reason why the ABP has duplicate this functionality is, at some time we needed to implement IUserTokenStore that's why reimplemented that method.
You can use ABP's method.